# Error while accessing variables

Tags: android, timer

I am getting errors while accessing the object of one class in another. Below is my code:

```
package FinalProj.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;

public class iFallApp extends Activity{
    public Object textView1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        //textview.setText("This is the iFall tab");
       // setContentView()
        setContentView(R.layout.ifallapp);

        View textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        MyCount counter = new MyCount(5000,1000);
        counter.start();


    }

    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            }

        iFallApp app1 = new iFallApp();

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            app1.textView1.setText("done");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }

}
```

I am trying to access textView1 of class iFallApp into class Mycount. However its not giving me an error for textView1, but error is method "setText(string)" is undefined for type object.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
 public Object textView1;
```

to

```
public TextView textView1;
```

and change

```
View textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

to

```
textView1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an instance variable called textView1 defined as an object in your iFallApp class.  This is what is being accessed in your line app1.textView1.setText("done")